# ViewBag Error using DropDownListFor in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag, dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to display a dropdownlistfor using a ViewBag that a pass data from Controller to view page,  but I get the following error:

> The best overloaded method match 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable, string, string)' has some invalid arguments "

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class CadastroCategoriaViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Construtores

    public CadastroCategoriaViewModel()
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region Propriedades

    /// <summary>
    /// Perfil de usuário em cadastro ou edição.
    /// </summary>
    public CategoriaFinanceira CategoriaFinanceira { get; set; }

    public bool eFilho { get; set; }
}
```

Inheriting this Model:

```
public class CategoriaFinanceira
{
    public int CategoriaFinanceiraID { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameLocalizavel(NomeMensagensCategoriaFinanceira.Nome, typeof(MensagensCategoriaFinanceira))]
    [ValidacaoCampoObrigatorio]
    [ValidacaoTamanhoTexto(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameLocalizavel(NomeMensagensCategoriaFinanceira.TipoPermiteLancamento, typeof(MensagensCategoriaFinanceira))]
    [ValidacaoCampoObrigatorio]
    public EnumTipoPermiteLancamento TipoPermiteLancamentoID { get; set; }

    [ValidacaoCampoObrigatorio]
    [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
    public EnumTipoLancamento TipoLancamentoID { get; set; }

    [ValidacaoCampoObrigatorio]
    public int EmpresaID { get; set; }

    //public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    public int? PaiCategoriaFinanceiraID { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoriaFinanceira PaiCategoriaFinanceira { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CategoriaFinanceira> FilhosCategoriasFinanceiras { get; set; }

    //public virtual CategoriaFinanceiraRelacao CategoriaFinanceiraRelacao { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameLocalizavel(NomeMensagensCategoriaFinanceira.UsuarioIdCadastro, typeof(MensagensCategoriaFinanceira))]
    [ValidacaoCampoObrigatorio]
    public int CadastroUsuarioID { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameLocalizavel(NomeMensagensCategoriaFinanceira.CadastroData, typeof(MensagensCategoriaFinanceira))]
    [ValidacaoCampoObrigatorio]
    public DateTime CadastroData { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameLocalizavel(NomeMensagensCategoriaFinanceira.AtualizacaoUsuarioID, typeof(MensagensCategoriaFinanceira))]
    public int? AtualizacaoUsuarioID { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameLocalizavel(NomeMensagensCategoriaFinanceira.AtualizacaoData, typeof(MensagensCategoriaFinanceira))]
    public DateTime? AtualizacaoData { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameLocalizavel(NomeMensagensCategoriaFinanceira.InativacaoUsuarioID, typeof(MensagensCategoriaFinanceira))]
    public int? InativacaoUsuarioID { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameLocalizavel(NomeMensagensCategoriaFinanceira.InativacaoData, typeof(MensagensCategoriaFinanceira))]
    public DateTime? InativacaoData { get; set; }
}
```

And the DropDownListFor that I'm trying to use

```
<section class="col col-6">
            <label class="select">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaFinanceira.PaiCategoriaFinanceiraID, new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoriasPai, "CategoriaFinanceiraID", "Nome"))
                <i></i>
            </label>
        </section>
```

I'm passing my ViewBag like this:

```
public ActionResult CadastrarFilho()
    {
        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        if (Session["Empresa"] != null)
        {
            empresa = ((Empresa)Session["Empresa"]);
        }

        var viewModel = new CadastroCategoriaViewModel();

        viewModel.eFilho = true;

        viewModel.CategoriaFinanceira = new CategoriaFinanceira();

        ViewBag.CategoriasPai = _servicoAppGerenciadorCategoriaFinanceira.ListarPorEmpresa(TokenAcesso, empresa.EmpresaID);

        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
```

Can some one give me a clue or a hint ?

Comment: Translate your error message to English

Comment: What does you `ListarPorEmpresa()` method return?

Comment: Return a list of CategoriaFinanceira. List<CategoriaFinanceira>. In this case, 99 resuts

Answer (score 0):

pass the data in selectlist from controller to view. Like below
In ccontroller

```
public ActionResult CadastrarFilho()
{
  .
  .      
   ViewBag.CategoriasPai = new SelectList(_servicoAppGerenciadorCategoriaFinanceira.ListarPorEmpresa(TokenAcesso, empresa.EmpresaID), "CategoriaFinanceiraID",  "Nome");

   return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

and in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaFinanceira.PaiCategoriaFinanceiraID, ViewBag.CategoriasPai  as SelectList())
```

hope this helps

Comment: I get the same error on my controller when I do this: "The best overloaded method match 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable, string, string)' has some invalid arguments " . And on my View, "Method name expected". But can you give a overview about what you say it please ?

Comment: debug ur controller at 'ViewBag.CategoriasPai' and see any value coming r error